# How to create a mysql database and tables dynamically using symfony and doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am working on building an application which would be used to create new child applications which have their own databases.

I know we can use doctrine bundle to create tables from entity classes in symfony. I would like to know if there is a way to create a new database and some tables within the database programmatically or dynamically.

I know we can use `php app/console doctrine:generate:database` from the composer prompt, but i would like to do this from a class or a controller action.

Do let me know if there is a way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either call exec() and drop the command in there or the better way, would be to follow the docs in symfony for calling console commands in a controller.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/command_in_controller.html

Comment: Thank you @Asperon. Also, would you know on how to make the database name a variable for the command.

Comment: The problem is i think doctine:database:create looks at the yaml. So you probably should just use straight mysql